# Why javascript can't get the style value but can change it?

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to pass the tag data to the function and read it in that function ,
I tried to pass the tag via "this" , i could change some style elements but i couldn't read the style data there. What is the problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JS</title>
<script>
function paint(tab){
    window.alert(tab.style.backgroundColor); // It can't show current color
    tab.style.backgroundColor="#000000";
}
</script>
<style>
div.vtab {
  background-color:#ff0000;
  height: 80px;
  left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div onclick="javascript:paint(this)" class="vtab" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get, also I assume you mean 'tab' rather than 'tag' in your question.

Comment: tab is just an argument name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `style` object on elements only has the style information applied *specifically* to the element, not information applied to it via stylesheets. So to start with, your `tab.style.backgroundColor` will be blank, because there's no `style="background-color: ..."` on the element.

To get the *computed* style of an element, you use the `getComputedStyle` function (on anything modern) or the `currentStyle` property (on old IE):

```
alert(getComputedStyle(tab).backgroundColor);
```

For old IE, a simple shim is easily added:

```
if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
    window.getComputedStyle = function(element, pseudo) {
        if (typeof pseudo !== "undefined") {
            throw "The second argument to getComputedStyle can't be polyfilled";
        }
        return element.currentStyle;
    };
}
```

Example:

```js
if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
  window.getComputedStyle = function(element, pseudo) {
    if (typeof pseudo !== "undefined") {
      throw "The second argument to getComputedStyle can't be polyfilled";
    }
    return element.currentStyle;
  };
}
var div = document.querySelector(".foo");
snippet.log("Background color before changing: " +
            getComputedStyle(div).backgroundColor);
setTimeout(function() {
  div.style.backgroundColor = '#4ff';
  snippet.log("Background color after changing: " +
              getComputedStyle(div).backgroundColor);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: #ff4;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">My background is yellow to start with, because of the class <code>foo</code>, then code turns it cyan</div>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you , with your changes it worked .

Comment: But when i applied the style specifically to the element it still not working.

Comment: Sorry it was my fault , you was right , bye